# What happens my service when app is updated?

Tags: android, service, google-play

I am writing an app with a service component. By it's very nature, this service will sit running in the background.

At any point in time my app may be updated by Google Play. i.e. A new APK downloaded and installed onto the device. When I follow this process with Eclipse ADT, the service stops running one I have uploaded a new version.

What happens when the app is updated from the Play Store? Is it something similar? And if so how can I restart the service automatically without having to get the user to intervene?

Thank you

Comment: Unless you make regular network calls from your service to google play to check the version (which I am not sure how to do) or to your own server  I don't think there is a generic method. There may even be a way to set for auto notifications in your Google Play developer console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application is updated, the system sends out two broadcasts: [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) (sent only to your application, available in API 12 (3.1) or higher) and [ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) (sent to every app, check `getData()` on the Intent to get the package name, available on all API levels).

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` that listens for the broadcast and starts your service.

I'd strongly recommend disabling any receiver listening for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast on Android 3.1+ devices as otherwise your receiver/process will get triggered on other apps as well (in that case, you'd want two receivers: one for <3.1, one for >=3.1 and use `android:enabled` with boolean resources to disable them appropriately based on API level).

Comment: This is great stuff.. Why should I not use ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED  for 3.1+. Why can't I just use this one for all and filter on the package name in Intent data? Thank you.

Comment: While it certainly works, `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` was specifically built to allow Android to do the filtering for you, preventing your app from having to do more work than necessary. This is very important for most apps where the default state is not running (and the price of starting up your process every time any app changes is a detriment to the whole system: think if many of your apps did this and how unusable your phone would be while updating apps).